# Two async software UARTs return unexpected repeated characters

Tags: timer, byte, microcontroller, cpu-registers, uart

I was going to post this on codereview.stackexchange.com but the problem is this code does not work correctly.

I have an AT89C4051 processor which only has one hardware UART, however I will attach two UART-based devices to it of which one is my computer. The configuration across all devices is 9600,N,8,1 (9600bps, no parity, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit)

I attempted to create two software-based UARTs with machine-optimized code that can interface between the two devices, however the data I received on my computer is incorrect.

I was expecting 'ABCD' or 'abcd' to appear on the screen but all I received was 'DDDD'.

What can I do here to fix this problem without resorting to buying extra hardware?

```
  ;dual 9600bps channels
  ;RX1,TX1 = uart channel
  ;RX2,TX2 = uart channel

  ;start with uart configuration
  org 0000h
  ljmp uartcfg

  ;every 1/2 bit time execute function
  org 000Bh
  sjmp swuartint

  SWCFG equ 20h ;serial config

  ;config for uart 1
  SWRI bit 20h.0        ;data fully received if SWRI set
  serrxslow bit 20h.2 ;bit flip-flop for receive. cpl 2x = 1 full bit time
  SWTI bit 20h.1      ;data fully transmitted if SWTI set
  sertxslow bit 20h.3 ;bit flip-flop for transmit. cpl 2x = 1 full bit time

  ;config for uart 2: same format
  SWRI2 bit 20h.4
  serrxslow2 bit 20h.6
  SWTI2 bit 20h.5
  sertxslow2 bit 20h.7

  SWUARTNO bit 21h.0 ;current Software Uart Number
  SWRNR bit 21h.1    ;Software Uart Receiver Not Ready
  SWTMP equ 0Fh      ;Temporary variable to pass indirect address value to register
  SBUFR2 equ 0Eh     ;Uart 2 received byte value
  SBUFR equ 0Dh      ;Uart 1 received byte value
  SBUFT2 equ 0Ch       ;Uart 2 sent byte value
  SBUFT equ 0Bh    ;Uart 1 sent byte value

  swuartint:
;1/2 bit time detected.
;save registers
push PSW
push ACC
;set register bank RS1:RS0 = 1:1 or 1:0 depending on UART wanted
;so we have our own private set of R0-R7 variables for each UART
setb RS1
mov C,SWUARTNO
mov RS0,C

;Get bit from UART 2
mov C,RX2
jb RS0,nour1
  mov C,RX1 ;Get bit from UART 1 if RS0 not set
nour1:
jb SWTI,extx
  ;Transmit routine is only used if transmit complete flag is NOT set.
  cpl sertxslow
  jnb sertxslow,extx
    ;Only do the real transmit work on full bit times
    ;save existing carry flag (it has received value)
    push PSW
    mov A,R2 ;R2=transmit counter to load
    jnz tnz
      ;Counter=0: Load transmitted value to R3 through temporary variable
      mov SWTMP,@R1
      mov R3,SWTMP
      ;Set counter to 1 and clear C to output start bit (of 0)
      inc A
      clr C
      sjmp extx1
    tnz:
    jnb ACC.3,tne
    jnb ACC.0,tne
      ;Counter is 9 so set transmit complete flag
      setb SWTI
      clr A ;set counter to 0 and set C to output stop bit (of 1)
      setb C
      sjmp extx1
    tne:
    ;Counter is between 1 and 8
    ;Save accumulator to R5 since push/pop wastes cycles
    mov R5,A
    mov A,R3 ;load accumulator with outgoing data
    RRC A    ;shift out one byte to C
    mov R3,A ;save data
    mov A,R5
    inc A ;increment count
    extx1:
    ;Use right transmit channel based on chosen UART number
    jb RS0,nour2
      mov TX1,C
      sjmp extx2
      nour2:
      mov TX2,C
    extx2:
    ;Save count
    mov R2,A
    ;and load back receiver value C
    pop PSW
extx:
mov A,R7 ;load receiving count
jnz rnz
  ;Counter=0. Store ready status
  mov SWRNR,C
  jc exrx
    ;increment counter only if start bit=0
    inc A
    clr serrxslow ;reset flip flop so we wait 1 bit time to get bit.
    sjmp exrx
rnz:
cpl serrxslow
jb serrxslow,exrx
  ;Counter > 0, 1 bit time waited
  jnb ACC.3,rne
  jnb ACC.0,rne
    ;Counter = 9. Status = Stop bit. 1=complete. 0=fail.
    mov SWRI,C
    ;Store data
    mov SWTMP,R4
    mov @R0,SWTMP
    ;Clear count
    clr A
    sjmp exrx
  rne:
  ;Counter = 1 to 8.
  ;Load data same way as transmit routine
  mov R6,A
  mov A,R4
  RRC A
  mov R4,A
  mov A,R6
  inc A ;increment count
exrx:
mov R7,A ;save count to receive count variable

;Don't switch UARTs when in the middle of a bit time
jnb sertxslow,nextuart
;Don't switch UARTs if receiver has data to process
jnb SWRNR,nextuart
  ;Don't switch UARTs if transmitter has data to process
  jnb SWTI,nextuart
    ;Switch UART
    cpl SWUARTNO
    ;Flip nibbles in configuration as each nibble
    ;belongs to its own UART
    mov A,SWCFG
    swap A
    mov SWCFG,A
  nextuart:
;restore registers and exit
pop ACC
pop PSW
  reti

  uartcfg:
setb RS1
setb RS0
mov R0,#SBUFR2 ;If RS1=RS0=1, @R0 = contents of SBUFR2
mov R1,#SBUFT2 ;If RS1=RS0=1, @R1 = contents of SBUFT2
clr RS0
mov R0,#SBUFR ;If RS1=1 and RS0=0, @R0 = contents of SBUFR
mov R1,#SBUFT ;If RS1=1 and RS0=0, @R1 = contents of SBUFT

clr RS1  ;Restore register bank (RS1=0, RS0=0)
mov SWCFG,#22h ;Set transmit complete to both UARTs at once
mov TH0,#0A0h  ;Value = 256-(((crystal/baud)/12)/2) = 9.6kbps 1/2 bit rate
mov TL0,#0A0h
mov TMOD,#22h ;8-bit timers auto reload
mov SP,#50h   ;get stack pointer away from our work
setb TR0      ;enable timer
mov IE,#082h  ;enable Timer 0 interrupt
  ljmp startapp     ;go to program


  ;serial port 1
  ;plugged into computer for data testing
  RX1 equ P3.0
  TX1 equ P3.1
  ;serial port 2
  RX2 equ P3.3
  TX2 equ P1.2 

  startapp:
; Trying to output 'ABCD' or 'abcd' but all I get is 'DDDD'

mov SBUFT,#0h ;Set character for UART 1
clr SWTI    ;clear complete flag
jnb SWTI,$  ;stall until character transmitted
mov SBUFT,#'A' ;repeat...
clr SWTI
jnb SWTI,$
mov SBUFT,#'B'
clr SWTI
jnb SWTI,$
mov SBUFT,#'C'
clr SWTI
jnb SWTI,$
mov SBUFT,#'D'
clr SWTI
jnb SWTI,$

mov SBUFT2,#0h ;Set character for UART 2
clr SWTI2    ;clear complete flag
jnb SWTI2,$      ;stall until character transmitted
mov SBUFT2,#'a' ;repeat...
clr SWTI2
jnb SWTI2,$
mov SBUFT2,#'b'
clr SWTI2
jnb SWTI2,$
mov SBUFT2,#'c'
clr SWTI2
jnb SWTI2,$
mov SBUFT2,#'d'
clr SWTI2
jnb SWTI2,$

  sjmp $
```